# How to extract http az function response to use in custom middleware?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, middleware

Use case: I want to use a custom middleware to do last minute modification to the http trigger string response.

I wrote up my custom middleware as:

```
internal sealed class MyCustomMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
  public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
  {
    await next(context); //returns "Hello"

    //I want modify response to becomes "Hello World"
  }
}
```

I register my custom middleware as:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
          .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker =>
          {
             worker.UseMiddleware<MyCustomMiddleware>();
          })
          .Build();

     host.Run();
```

I cannot extract the response string "Hello" after the function execution. I tried to use GetHttpResponseData() but it returns null.

> context.GetHttpResponseData().Body

Answer (score 2):

**I tried below code to *extract response of Http Triggered Azure Function* and *modify its context in custom middleware*.**

- Thanks to @[Sil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73080248/19991670) for the code.

**Custom Middleware:**

```cs
 public sealed class MyCustomMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
 {
     public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
     {
        // Fetching the Http Azure function response
         var req = await context.GetHttpRequestDataAsync();

        // Modifying the response
         var res = req!.CreateResponse();
         await res.WriteStringAsync("Function response changed");
         context.GetInvocationResult().Value = res;
     }
 }
```

**Program.cs:**

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker =>
    {
        worker.UseMiddleware<MyCustomMiddleware>();
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**Console Output:**

```cs
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5455 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.27.5.21554

[2023-12-13T12:15:21.065Z] Found C:\Users\<user>\Source\Repos\FunctionApp18\FunctionApp18\FunctionApp18.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2023-12-13T12:15:31.028Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 26252) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2023-12-13T12:15:31.229Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        Function1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7299/api/Function1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2023-12-13T12:15:36.296Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000XXXXXXC'.
[2023-12-13T12:15:44.167Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=7f684090-4XXXXXXXXXXXXe-1f825fe62a1f)
[2023-12-13T12:15:44.489Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=7f684090-46a6-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1f825fe62a1f, Duration=363ms)
```

**Initial Response:**

[image]

**Modified Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, though it seems this solution compose a brand new response.  I wonder if you can compose the repsonse based on the output of your function dynamically? Such as appending to it like  "Welcome to Azure Functions! Pravallika"

Comment: I will check and update